# Web Font not loading

Tags: html, css

First and foremost, I have tried searching and can't really find anything that will help this specific problem.

Basically I have my website http://www.jamesendres.com and I am trying to load a custom web font from  http://justanotherfoundry.com/facit-web.  When I was developing my website on my local machine it worked flawlessly, but when I uploaded all of my files to Dreamhost, the fonts aren't being loaded..  I opened Firebug and apparently the fonts are being downloaded last so I think this might have something to do with why they aren't being loaded.  But I could be wrong.  In my main.css file is where all of my font-related configurations are.

For help purposes I have made the homepage default to whatever the browsers default is to show it's not working:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'FacitWeb-Extralight';
    src:url('http://webfonts.justanotherfoundry.com/Facit/FXL');
    font-weight:bold
}

p, li{
font-size:14px;
/*font-family:'FacitWeb-Extralight', Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;*/
font-family: FacitWeb-Extralight;
line-height:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of simply writing a direct @font-face, you should use one of the font-face generators out there.

I pesonally recommend [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).  They keep the generator up to date.

The benefits include

- Advanced font-face syntax for correct loading across browsers
- Automatic IE-style font generation
- Good fallback design when @font-face is not supported.

Comment: I would use this the only problem is that the font that I am trying to use to free for web use but paid for if I want to download it.  I've been trying to mess around with Font Squirrel but I dont see an option where I can link the other font to the generator.

Comment: Well, you can use the Font Squirrel declaration, just manually substituting the correct paths.  Possibly your issue then is linking to the other website.  It might be a security issue.  Also, if you want it to work under IE, you must have access to an EOT font.

Comment: After some messing around with it, I found a message when I tried to access the font stylesheet on their website with the inspect element, turns out my domain wasnt registered.  Thanks though for the tip.  I'm going to start using Font Squirrel